# How to make sure Homebrew path is set up properly on Mac

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, homebrew, zsh

When I install brew on a MacOS (Ventura) using

> /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL
> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

... the very last part of the install script outputs:

> Run these two commands in your terminal to add Homebrew to your PATH:
> (echo; echo 'eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"') >> /Users/pieface/.zprofile
> eval "$(/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv)"

However, there is no ".zprofile" file in my user directory.  To my knowledge the file that contains my path configuration is .zshrc, a file which seems unmodified by the install script.

To further confuse matters, typing "which brew" immediately after the install script completes indicates that it *is* in my path (it works).  But how can this be possible?  And why would they suggest manually adding it to path using above instructions if it already works?

Would it be acceptable/equivalent to simply add

```
eval "$/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv"
```

to my .zshrc file?

I am afraid to proceed for fear of borking my system.

I'm newish to linux/mac/bash stuff... some clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: .zshrc is processed only for interactive shells. .zprofile is processed for login shells, so you have to think about under which conditions you want to see this effect. Actually, .zshenv would also be an option (this file is processed by every zsh). Aside from this, I would be reluctant to put such an `eval` blindly into my startup files. At the very least, run `brew shellenv` first manually, to see what this produces, and then decide.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [introduction](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) about zprofile and other config files,
the `>>` will create a file if there isn't before.

And also a [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735819/what-does-command-eval-opt-homebrew-bin-brew-shellenv-actually-do) about `eval "$/usr/local/bin/brew shellenv"`